# store multiple options in localStorage for a quiz

Tags: local-storage

I'm trying to create a quiz for an ipad app using localstorage. I have succesfully created a quiz that remembers the options you click, and I can check if the answer is correct.

However, for some questions there are multiple answers, and I'd like to be able to store the multiple answers as an array for that question.

My quiz currently stores the answer under a key that is named by the class of the parent div. The answer depends on which LI you click on. Please see below for my code.

I'd like the option of being able to store multiple answers per question, how would I do this based on the code I have? I'm quite new to javascript.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    body{
        text-align: center;
    }

    #questions{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 802px;
        height: 602px;
    }

    /*look for any class that has the word slide in it*/
    [class*="slide"]{
        padding: 20px;
        background: #666;
        width: 760px;
        height: 560px;
        border: 1px dashed #333;
    }
    [class*="slide"]:nth-child(odd){
        background: #999;
    }

    b{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
    }


    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="questions">
            <div class="slide1">
                <h1>What is h2o?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>A Pencil</li>
                    <li>Liquid water</li>
                    <li>A mobile phone network</li>
                    <li>Paper</li>
                </ul>
                <p>check</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <h1>What is 2 + 2?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                </ul>
                <p>check</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide3">
                <h1>What is a whale?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>A mammal</li>
                    <li>A fish</li>
                    <li>A bird</li>
                    <li>A country</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide4">
                <h1>What phone do you prefer?</h1>
            <ul>
                    <li>iPhone 4s</li>
                    <li>iPhone 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide5">
                <h1>What is 5 + 5?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>10</li>
                    <li>7</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide6">
                <h1>What is the capital city of England?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>London</li>
                    <li>Staines</li>
                    <li>Bognor Regis</li>
                    <li>Luton</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide7">
                <h1>What colour is a red phone box?</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Blue</li>
                    <li>Red</li>
                    <li>Pink</li>
                    <li>Mauve</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <b></b>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*
        //
        //  quiz storer and answer checker
        //  Author: Tjobbe Andrews
        //  v1.0, 13/02/2013
        //  - keeps a record in localStorage of the answers you chose, then checks them on an ad hoc basis
        //
        */

        //on clicking the answers in the li's..
        $("li").click(function(){
            //..create a variable called answer based on the content of that li..
            var answer = $(this).html();
            //..and create a variable called question based on the class of the parent div
            var question = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
            //then store the key value pair of question and answer
            localStorage.setItem(question, answer);
            //just makes sure that it's writing to the LS db
            $("b").html(localStorage.getItem(question));
        });

        //click the p tag to check what we've got stored for this div - ad hoc
        $('p').click(function(){
            var slideNumber = $(this).closest('div').attr('class');
            var answer = localStorage.getItem(slideNumber);
            if(answer !== "Liquid water"){
                alert('wrong');
            }
            else if(answer == "Liquid water"){
                alert("right");
            }
        });

    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And yes, I do know I'm using jQuery as well as JS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store multiple values in localStorage you can put them into an object and `JSON.stringify` it as a value to localStorage:

```
    var answersObject = {
      answer1: 'yes',
      answer2: 'no',
      answer3: 'maybe'
    };

    localStorage.setItem(question, JSON.stringify(answersObject));
```

To get them back from localStorage you should use `JSON.parse`

```
    storedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(question));
```

Now you can get your answers as `storedObject.answer1`, `storedObject.answer2` etc.